# c# - XAML - extra space under menu items in app bar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Whenever i added the menu items in app bar, an extra line or space is coming under the menu items. I don't know how to remove it. It really disturbs look a lot. herewith i have added that menu by image. Kindly, help me to get rid of that extra space.

My XAML CODE:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Default" Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="True" IsVisible="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/folder.png" Text="about" Click="more1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/next.png" Text="goto" Click="gotopage"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="rate this app" Click="rateapp"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="like us" Click="like"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

OUTPUT APP BAR BY ABOVE CODE:

[image]

Comment: That's just how the application bar works. Check any of the standard apps to see what I mean (store, games, etc). Even the customized `ApplicationBar` classes I have seen don't behave differently.

Comment: nope. goto Nokia Wallet app, it doesn't have any spaces in app bar.

Comment: That's not a standard application. Not only that, but it's from Nokia, which Microsoft has probably given some private API access to in order to theme their phones how they want.

Comment: It also depends on the number of menu items you have. It seems like anything under 3 has the space and anything 3 or over does not.

Comment: not only nokia, i have watched several apps that contains no space under menu items in app bar

Comment: Can you provide an example of an app with 2 menu items that does not have the space?

Comment: yes you are right. so, there is no way to get rid is that space. right ? Just give this comment as an answer, i will mark it by an answer.

Comment: You can tweak this using CSS overrides.  I'd have to look it up or debug it to get the exact ones that are being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it's the default behavior of the application bar to have this space when there are 2 or less menu items. You can get rid of the space by adding another menu item (throw in a help or about us or something) so that you have 3 menu items, or by creating your own application bar. The second route seems really overkill for such a small issue though.

Answer (score 2):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/6920301e-50a4-40fc-930b-28ae12a81cc6/extra-space-in-applicationbar-with-4-menu-items this link is helpful. The number of items should be odd. Otherwise we cannot avoid empty space.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the App Bar only has a few sizes that it will display.  one item, three items, and five items.  Thus why you get an extra space if you have 4 items or 2 items.